# Is there a way to impute or predict the NANs in this triangular dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, imputation, triangular

This `DataFrame` has values over the upper left triangle and the diagonal, with the rest of values being NANs[image: 1]

I don't want to use a looping linear regression model which would work on a sample size of 1.
I assume there is a simple way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: You need to decide how to fill the values. It can be with the mean, median, min, max, random, a specific function, etc. Use the fillna() method.

Comment: The values are decreasing from the left in each row separately, any of these options would not capture the decreasing nature in the pattern of the data

Comment: You would find a pattern. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example ( max 5 rows/columns and the matching expected output), as **text** (ideally, code to produce a `DataFrame`), give q but of background on what is the data, and explain the logic of filling.

Comment: The first column of the data is the numbers of monthly subscribers to a business for the first month of their subscription. Each column and each row represents the passage of one month. Which makes the subsequent cells in each row, the retention of customers for the upcoming months.
I can get 5 complete rows for older dates, but will that work with any ML model?